# C++: constexpr fibonacci sequence evaluation

Tags: c++

I'm studying constexpr and trying to implement an example in Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed. Page 312.  My understanding was computation of `fib(45)` should be done at compile time, however my results suggest the computation is taking place at run time.

Does anyone know where I have gone wrong in establishing computation of `fib(45)` at compile time using `constexpr`?

Thanks for your guidance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

constexpr int fib_(int n)
{
    return (n < 2) ? 1 : fib_(n - 1) + fib_(n - 2);
}

constexpr int ftbl[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
constexpr int fib(size_t n)
{
    return (n < sizeof(ftbl)/sizeof(*ftbl)) ? ftbl[n] : fib_(n); }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << fib(45) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATED CODE PER SUGGESTION:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned int fibr(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    return fibr(n - 1) + fibr(n - 2);
}

constexpr unsigned int ftbl[] { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
constexpr unsigned int fib(size_t n)
{
    return (n < sizeof(ftbl)/sizeof(*ftbl)) ? ftbl[n] : fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2) {
        if (string(argv[1]) == "r") {
            unsigned long x = fibr(44);
        cout << x << endl;
        }
    } else {        
        constexpr unsigned long x = fib(44);
    cout << x << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`constexpr` means that a function *could* be evaluated at compile time.

This statement:

```
cout << fib(45) << endl;
```

is not a context that requires compile time evaluation of `fib`, so the compiler may or may not evaluate this at run time.

You can force it to be evaluated at compile time like this:

```
constexpr auto res = fib(42);
cout << res << endl;
```

Comment: Oddly I find that computation of fib(45) per your recommendation takes much less time for the compiler to find the result, then the alternative originally posted calculation during runtime.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're measuring. If you measure just the run time, then yes, this version should be faster, since a lot of the work is done at compile time.

Comment: I measured the compile time for `constexpr fib()` result and that compile time was faster then runtime for non-constexpr `fibr()` fibonacci calculation.  Which means for some reason the compiler finds the constexpr fib answer faster than the runtime only version.  That was odd, perhaps recursion works faster in the compiler?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. There are a lot of factors here; the recursion could be relevant. Also, at run time you are measuring program startup time, and the time to stream output to the console, so that could be relevant too.

Comment: I accidentally forgot to use `constexpr unsigned long` and used `unsigned long`.  Now the `constexpr` code runs in 0.00 sec, which the other code path is 8.30 sec.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: That makes sense. If you measure the compile time, you should see the difference there. Happy to help :)